Create a Group Policy Object with Startup Script through Command LIne in Active Directory
I need to create a GPO with a startup script to install an MSI.
I have tried searching in the Microsoft's Documentation but i can't find a cmdlet that will allow me to do that. I would like to know if this in any way through a script.
Edit: I found that Set-GPRegistryValue this command can be used to change the registry values to change the computer and user configurations in a GPO. with some more research i found that the scripts are stored at "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Startup this registry value so i tried to do something like this
    $key = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Startup\0"
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "$key\0" -ValueName "Script" -Type String -Value $ScriptName
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "$key\0" -ValueName "Parameters" -Type String -Value ""
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "$key\0" -ValueName "IsPowershell" -Type DWord -Value 0
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key $key -ValueName "DisplayName" -Type String -Value "Install AnyDesk"
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key $key -ValueName "FileSysPath" -Type String -Value $scriptsFolderPath
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key $key -ValueName "GPO-ID" -Type String -Value $gpoId
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key $key -ValueName "SOM-ID" -Type String -Value $domainDN
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key $key -ValueName "GPOName" -Type String -Value $GPOName

but i couldn't this script didn't even set the first registry key properly and i can't figure out where i am going wrong.
Edit: I would also like to know if i am making the right registry key changes for adding a startup script or if i can make some other changes to create a GPO for software installation.

Do you receive error messages when you run this script? If so, please [edit] your post and add these messages in full

No i don't get any errors when i run the script i just don't see the registry value being set in the registry editor.

Normally, an Active Directory Domain GPO created centrally one time, and it will be automatically applied to Active Directory domain member PCs and Active Directory users based on the GPO settings.
In this case, you are trying to create a GPO within a GPO (startup script to set registry values) as far as I understand. If the PCs are domain members, edit a central GPO once to include MSI setup and apply it to computers. If the PCs are not domain members, they become less manageable, so every PC should be differently set.
My suggestion is: If you can not add the client computers (PCs) to Active Directory Domain, then work on one of the PCs and prepare the PC for MSI setup and include the MSI setup in Local GPO of the computer. If somehow the  software that is installed by the policy is corrupted OR a PC reinstall is done, that specific software will be installed by the Local GPO next time the policy is applied. When that reference PC local policy is approved, you can export the policy and import to the other PCs using LGPO.exe utility.
LGPO Utility
Ref: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/ba-p/701045
As I tried to emphasize above, if the PCs are domain members, there will be no need for export/import Local GPOs would not be necessary. GPO is defined once on the domain controllers using Group Policy Management Console (GPMC) . Then it is automatrically applied to domain members whose scopes fall into applied GPO boundary (Domain GPOs may be applied to Sites, Domain, OUs and additional WMI Filtering can be used to apply the policy to only chosen PCs / users in the related Site,OU,Domain..

I think i couldn't explain my problem properly what i actually need to know is for Software installation or Startup Script which Registry keys are required to be changed I have tried to change the keys above but i can't don't think they did the job.

The right and recommended way of deploying a computer startup script to a Windows computer is assigning this script via Group Policy, not using a Powershell script that updates local registry.  In addition the right and recommended way of deploying a group policy is using Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) or Group Policy Management Console (Gpmc.msc).  I do not think these method are documented and supported at vendor site.
